# NSString to NSDate conversion using NSDateFormatter > date way off

Tags: ios, objective-c

Trying to convert a datetime from `NSString` to `NSDate` using `NSDateFormatter`. I know it should be a simple task, but it's not - the converted `NSDate` is whole 20 days off. 
I cannot find the cause for this. Already tried every solution I could find (different locales, time zones, formattings ...) but no luck so far.

Here's a code sample:

```
NSString *strDate = @"24.01.2014 08:17:10";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CET"]];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:strDate];
```

output of dte is "04.01.2014 08:17:10". As you can see, the time is correct, but the date is way off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your time format, `YYYY` should be `yyyy`.

```
NSString *strDate = @"24.01.2014 08:17:10";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CET"]];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:strDate];
```

Will give me as output : `2014-01-24 07:17:10 +0000`

Comment: Ah. I'm blind. Not a good day for programming it seems. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
NSString *strDate = @"24.01.2014 08:17:10";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:strDate];
```